# why does this command block code not work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This:
`/testforblock ~ ~+1 ~ minecraft:chest {Items:[{id: @p{SelectedItem {id:minecraft:stick}}}]}`

Command block output:
`{Items:[{id:' is not a valid number`

Please help.

info i have only tried this i want to know why this code does not work

Comment: Help us understand your question better.  What are you trying to do with your command block?

Comment: i want to check if the item the player is holding matches any item in the chest

Comment: Could you provide some resources, on what, how and why you tried specifically what you did? I guess you already got the official documentation at hand?

Comment: i have only tried this i want to know why this code does not work or if there are any alternitives

Comment: Change your question please. State what you want to do, then in the descriptiong state what you have tried and what it did/didn't do

Comment: Well first off, plusses aren't used in commands. Second, why is the @p selector in the middle rather than at the beginning?

Answer (score 4):

The format for your command is off, and you're trying to combine two commands in one. First you try to detect certain items in the chest, then you suddenly switch to trying to detect a player holding a certain item. I'll explain the parts of the command in order for detecting a chest with certain items.

You first need to start off your command with `/testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:chest`. This part shows that you are testing for a chest directly under your feet.

Next you have to specify the data value of the chest; in this case, which way the chest is pointing. If the lock on the chest is facing North, the data value is 2. If it's facing South, it's 3. West is 4, and East is 5. A wildcard is -1, which doesn't require any specific direction. So far, your command is `/testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:chest -1`.

Your next step is to specify the data tag, or what items you want to test for in the chest. To test for any amount of sticks (I'm assuming this is what you want as you put it in the original post) the data tag would be `{Items:[{id:minecraft:stick}]}`.

If we combine all the parts, your new command is:

```
/testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:chest -1 {Items:[{id:minecraft:stick}]}
```